# Custom control doesn't expose image properties in the Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, custom-controls, designer

I have made a custom trackbar control, mostly as an exercise. I know i could/should have just inherited what i needed instead of reinventing the wheel, but i have learned a lot during my endeavour.
Now, i have a lot of properties, and all of them shows up in the designer apart from a couple of image properties. This is what i have, modelled on the other working properties (those are ints and Colors and what not, and they all work as expected...), so maybe i should be doing Images in some other way. Bottom line, i don't know what i'm doing :)

**EDIT :** My custom control is in a Windows Forms solution (VC# 2008 Express), and to clarify, my problem is that some of my control's properties (the Image properties) isn't showing in the properties-tab during design-time.

**EDIT 2 :** After reading up on DependencyProperty and totally failed to understand that concept (I'm very noob at programmin teh codez or what you gurus call this black voodoo magic??). I have gotten used to letting the IDE fix all my troubles, and i was pleased to see the IDE happily showing my other properties, such as `Color BarColor`, `int Value` etc. etc. Why would `Image LeftImage` be any different, a lot of the standard controls have Image properties and maybe it's naïve of me to think that the IDE can figure all of my mistakes out, but surely the guys at Microsoft did not construct a new editor every time they had to set an image property in their controls. My bet is that they reused something, which i should be able to do as well.

I'm stuck :(

Here's my crappy CoD3Z anyway:

```
private Image _LeftImage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the small image appearing to the left of the trackbar
    /// </summary>

    [Description("The small image appearing to the left of the trackbar"),
    Category("Appearance"),
    DefaultValue(typeof(Image),"null"),
    Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]

    public Image LeftImage
    {
        private get { return _LeftImage; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Height != 16 || value.Width != 16)
            {
                _LeftImage = new Bitmap(value,new Size(16,16));
            }
            else _LeftImage = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

By the way, what is the difference between DefaultValue and DefaultValueAttribute?

Thanks for any pointers and help!
/Mikael

Comment: "difference between DefaultValue and DefaultValueAttribute" - They're actually the same thing. When you're adding an attribute to something, you can omit the "Attribute" suffix. [DefaultValue(...)] creates an instance of the DefaultValueAttribute class.

Comment: Well then, do i wan't to create an instance, or is it already instanciated? I'll try the other one and see ;)

Comment: Ok, as one could have concluded from your explanation, changing from `DefaultValue` to `DefaultValueAttribute` didn't make a difference...

Comment: Ok, so I found the answer but I can't answer my own question since I'm a new user. Anyway, most if not all microsoft classes contain an editor, so in my case it should be simple: <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.imageeditor.aspx>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.imageeditor.aspx

Consider this solved.

Comment: This was correct all along, the problem was that i used a private accessor. If i remove it it works! Check out my duplicate question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956231/help-i-cant-get-my-properties-into-the-designer-propertygrid

Answer (score 0):

For Show the Image in the Designer you need to overrides the OnPaint Method drawing it.

DefaultValue is the same that DefaultValueAttribute. All Attributes in .NET are clases that inherits from System.Attribute, and all those class are something like Name**Attribute** where Attribute is fixed. Then "DefaultValue" is like an Alias.

Comment: I think that he wants to display property, not the image itself.

Answer (score -1):

Your example doesn't show what exactly is your problem but if you create custom control and want to access its properties from designer you should use smth like that:

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(CustomControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, ValueChanged));
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into your suggestion. I don't quite understand what a DependencyProperty is and what it is good for. For my other properties, it seems so easy, it just pops into the properties-list magically, along with it's appropriate color-pickers and text-boxes. I thought Image-properties would also show up auto-magically, i mean my control is not the first with an image-property, right?

Comment: Registering your property in class via DependencyProperty alows for binding to it in Xaml

Comment: @mickey I am sure that you can do it in the similar way as you did for other properties. I just don't know how... Looking forward for another answer.

Comment: @Dariusz Wickowski - So DependencyProperty is something one would use in a WPF-context, but maybe not in my Windows Forms project (VC# 2008 Express) , am i right? I tried to read up on both DependencyProperty and FrameworkPropertyMetadata, but i just don't understand it.

Comment: @mickey, that's correct -- DependencyProperty is strictly a WPF thing. This answer was posted before you explicitly said you were using WinForms (though it was apparent if you looked closely enough -- your code sample calls Invalidate, which doesn't exist in WPF). This answer apparently assumed WPF instead.

Comment: @Joe White, thanks, i should have been more clear on the fact that it is WinForms and not WPF! Do you have any thoughts on my problem? Does it look alright to you? Could it be some other problem? A typo somewhere? I only catch problems that the IDE highlights for me :)

Comment: @mickey I am sorry for my missunderstanding, I can't help you then in WinForms