# Help, i can't get my properties into the designer PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, editor, designer, propertygrid

What is wrong with this? The property LeftImage doesn't show up in the PropertyGrid (WinForms .NET 3.5)

```
    private Image _LeftImage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the small image appearing to the left of the trackbar
    /// </summary>

    [
    Description("The small image appearing to the left of the trackbar"),
    Category("Appearance"),
    EditorAttribute(typeof(System.Drawing.Design.ImageEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor)),
    DefaultValueAttribute(typeof(Image),"null"),
    Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)
    ]

    public Image LeftImage
    {
        private get { return _LeftImage; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Height != 16 || value.Width != 16)
            {
                _LeftImage = new Bitmap(value,new Size(16,16));
            }
            else _LeftImage = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Where do i go wrong??? The IDE doesn't complain about anything, and it compiles fine, and all the other properties show up alright. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the private accessor on get statement of LeftImage.  Change it to

```
get { return m_LeftImage; }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that! I'll mark your answer in a couple of days, i cannot try it right now!

Comment: Now I tried it, it worked! But is public the only accessor i can have? What if i for some reason wanted to use a restrictive accessor? Is that an impossibility?

Comment: No, you will a non-restrictive accessor.  You are creating this property and adding it to the property grid for a reason.  You're setting Browsable=true, so classes outside of this one can set this setting in the designer.  That is pretty much the definition of a public property.   It doesn't really make sense any other way.  Imagine a TextBox, that has a designer property of MultiLine, but you can't access it from the designer.  What would be the point?

Comment: Obviously, that's not a shocker when you think about it... I'm just being retarded...

Comment: Can I make the property be public during design-time, but become private during runtime? (Maybe this is another silly question, I could not think of a situation where you would want to do that...)

Comment: No, because design time is essentially run time.  All the stuff you do during "design" is translated into calls during the InitializeComponent() of your constructor (during run time).

Comment: You can "fake it" using basic programming strategies.   like set { if (_LeftImage != null) throw new Exception("tried to set it again"); else { _LeftImage = value; }